# Is Attestation Verifiable Credentials Type repo demo available in c#?

Tags: azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I have tested successfully [idtokenhint demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet/tree/main/1-asp-net-core-api-idtokenhint) and I am trying unsucessfully attestation [verifiable credentials type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/credential-design#attestations) , similar to the [Woodgrave Employee Onboarding Demo](https://woodgroveemployee.azurewebsites.net/verification), is this code available in c#?

In my case I need the Authenticator to request the VerifiedCredentialExpert VC first but I don't see how to trigger this on Authenticator, I tried this on issuance_request_config.json file, I also tried adding requestedCredentials to type VerifiedCredentialExpert as you see below to suggest to Authenticator to get this first, but didn't change the error behaviour:

```
"includeQRCode": false,
"callback": {
  //In this sample code we will overwrite the callback and use the HOSTNAME dynamicall
  //make sure you use ngrok or something like that when running on a local devbox. 
  //The MS AAD VC Request service needs to be able to reach the callback URI
  "url": "https://YOURPUBLICREACHABLEHOSTNAME/api/issuer/issuanceCallback",
  "state": "STATEWILLBESETINCODE",
  "headers": {
    "api-key": "OPTIONAL API-KEY for ISSUANCE CALLBACK API"
  }
},
//The Authority is the DID from your MS AAD Verifiable Credential service, you can copy this from the VC page in azure portal
"authority": "did:ion: THIS IS YOUR DID FROM THE VC PAGE IN AZURE PORTAL WHICH IS SET IN THE SAMPLE BY COPYING THE VALUE FROM APPSETTINGS.JSON   ",
"registration": {
  "clientName": "Verifiable Test Register Verifiable Credential"
},
//The type needs to be the same as defined in the rules json definitione. The manifest can be copied after the credential has been
//created in the azure portal
"type": "VerifiedTestRegistration",
"manifest": "CREDENTIAL URL IN THIS SAMPLE WILL BE COPIED FROM APPSETTINGS.JSON",
//Recommendation is to protect issuance payload with a PIN code. 
//The pincode is set to a random value in code and will be displayed in the UI to the user
"pin": {
  "value": "123456",
  "length": 4
},
//This is an example payload which will be used in the rules file of the credential.
//The rules files maps information from the ID Token (hint) to the VC
"claims": {
  "country_of_registry": "",
  "registration_number": "",
},
//You can request multiple verifiable credentials at once that's whty the requestCredentials is an array
"requestedCredentials": [
  {
    "type": "VerifiedCredentialExpert",
    "purpose": "Required presentation of verifiable credentials expert to get Test Registration card.",
    //You can trust multiple issuers who might be issuing the same credential type (for example certifications or diplomas)
    //You need to specify at least 1 trusted issuer DID, for this sample code we copy the IssuerAuthority from appsettings to the request
    //"acceptedIssuers": [ "did:ion: copied from your VC portal in this sample the code copies it from APPSETTINGS.JSON" ]
    "acceptedIssuers": [ "theaccepetedidissuer" ]
  }

]
```

}

These are the display and rules:

Display definition

```
      {
    "locale": "en-US",
    "card": {
      "title": "Test Verified Credential",
      "issuedBy": "TheIssuer",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "logo": {
        "uri": "https://example.com/image.png",
        "description": "Test  Verified Credential"
      },
      "description": "Use this card to verify."
    },
    "consent": {
      "title": "Do you want to get your Test Verified Credential?",
      "instructions": "Sign in with your Verified Credential Expert Card to get your card."
    },
    "claims": [
      {
        "claim": "$.vc.country_of_registry",
        "label": "Country of Registry",
        "type": "String"
      },
      {
        "claim": "$.vc.registration_number",
        "label": "Registration Number",
        "type": "String"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Rules definition:

```
{
  "attestations": {
    "presentations": [
      {
        "mapping": [
          {
            "outputClaim": "firstName",
            "required": true,
            "inputClaim": "$.vc.credentialSubject.given_name",
            "indexed": false
          },
          {
            "outputClaim": "lastName",
            "required": true,
            "inputClaim": "$.vc.credentialSubject.family_name",
            "indexed": false
          }
        ],
        "required": true,
        "credentialType": "VerifiedCredentialExpert",
        "contracts": [
          "https://verifiedid.did.msidentity.com/v1.0/tenants/id/verifiableCredentials/contracts/abcd/manifest"
        ],
        "trustedIssuers": [
          "did:ion:thedid"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "idTokenHints": [
      {
        "mapping": [
          {
            "outputClaim": "countryOfRegistry",
            "required": true,
            "inputClaim": "$.country_of_registry",
            "indexed": false
          },
          {
            "outputClaim": "registrationNumber",
            "required": true,
            "inputClaim": "$.registration_number",
            "indexed": true
          }
        ],
        "required": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "validityInterval": 2592000,
  "vc": {
    "type": [
      "VerifiedTestRegistration"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am testing on iphone12 pro latest iOS version installed.

[Question as posted in this git project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet/issues/41) but unfortunately got no help.

Thank you for your help, Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Sergio,

A few things that you should review on the sample:
On the rules file:

1. For the VC, you can remove the contract but leave the VCType

On the display file:
2. I also added the claims that were obtained from the VC in your case first_name and last_name.

After doing that, my sample worked via Postman directly working with the Request API, try to get that working first and then make it work in C#

One thing that I'm still investigating is that I didn't notice a presentation on the requested VC type being recorded. I believe it should have one, but I'm still following up with the team. Try it and let us know if it works

Comment: Thank you @Juan Camilo Ruiz, unfortunately my post is 3 months old and we moved on, unable to get back to this now.